# Excel: =SWITCH() not working with wildcard character *

Tags: excel, excel-formula, switch-statement

I have one column that contains age, gender, weight. (I get the spreadsheet from an outside source, and there is no way to get the data in a different format)

`9 - 10 Male 60.1 - 67lbs`

I made a formula in a new column to pull out the gender with switch and the wild card character.

`=SWITCH(A2, "*Male*", "Male", "*Female*", "Female", "ERROR")`

However, having the wildcard character there does not work, it breaks the formula. Is this a restriction on the switch statement or is my syntax wrong?

I need to also pull out the age and weight, an example of ages I would look for: 8-9, 10-11, 12-14, etc. I was thinking this formula with the wild card character would work, but I guess not. Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the format, with a variable in your examples being spaces before/after the hyphen, try this:  (It may not work if your formats are much different than what you have shown):

```
Age:    =INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($A2)," -","-"),"- ","-")," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198},99)),1)
Sex:    =INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($A2)," -","-"),"- ","-")," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198},99)),2)
Wt:     =INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($A2)," -","-"),"- ","-")," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198},99)),3)
```

The nested `SUBSTITUTE`'s part of the formula condenses `" - "`, `"- "`, `" -"` to just a single hyphen so we can use `space` as a separator between the three segments.

[image]

Comment: I just saw this answer. I will try it later, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find or Search for this. Check for *Female* first since *Male* would be found in *Female* in a case insensitive search.

```
=if(isnumber(search("female", a2)), "Female", if(isnumber(search("male", a2)), "Male", "Error"))
```

Comment: I think this works for 2 values right? but, what if I am looking for more then 2? Like the age example above, I would try to pull out the age but it could be: 7 - Under, 8-9, 10-11, 12-14, 15-17, 18-33, 33 - older. I don't think this would work for those, correct?

Comment: IFS might be appropriate or CHOOSE with MATCH.